# How do ASP.NET areas map to teams?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to understand the concept of an MVC Area.  I have read the following article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/714356/Areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC

1. In the linked article; there are areas for: Men; Women and Home.  Where do you put the ASP.NET Identity classes? Homes?
2. Do you have any folders e.g. Controller; Model etc in the root folder? The root folder is the same folder as the Areas folder
3. Are areas used so that a large application can be worked on my multiple teams.  For example, team 1 works on area 1 and team 2 works and area 2 and team x works on area x etc?
4. Say there are three teams.  Is it possible for each team to create a new MVC project to work on.  Then at deployment time the areas are combined to deploy as one web application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. simply speaking areas are mvc project inside mvc project. You can use global ASP.NET Identity classes -  in main mvc project or even configure for every area, but is it realy need to you?
2. You can have  Controller; Model etc in the root folder in main mvc projects, also you can create it's inside every area. it depend from purpose. In most cases you will have them as in main as inside every area.
3. NO. areas used for Separation of the functional, creating something similar to modules. team must work with task< not with area. which task to work for team -  it's jira or something similar. No relation to areas.
4. yes. it possible. but will be very difficult. for this purpose use version control and branches.

Comment: Thanks.  With regards to point three - how do you split an MVC app so that multiple teams can work on it?

Comment: it is called continues integration. you no need to see in way to split project. you must learn how to use version control. project must be only one. but different teams will work in different branches and at the end pf sprint they merge to master for example.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_(version_control) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(version_control)

Comment: Thanks.  What about this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307467/how-to-create-an-asp-net-application-from-multiple-projects-for-team-d

Comment: multi project and single project with areas it is not the same.

Comment: Nearly ready to accept - I have two more questions.  1) Would you have an Area containing Administration? 2) Would you have one Administration area per website or one administration area per area?